# How can I stop my one type of objects interacting with each other but other types?

Tags: physics, coronasdk

For example, I have items falling from up and I don't want those items to interact with each other(one should pass through other) but I want them to interact with other objects for example ground. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use collision filters

Here this is what you looking for [Collision Filters](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/collision-filter)